ImportError: cannot import name 'Settings' from 'settings' python
Here is my main module:
import sys
import pygame

from settings import Settings

class AlienInvasion:

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()  

        
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))  
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

        self.bg_color = self.settings.bg_color

    def run_game(self):
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()

        
            self.screen.fill(self.bg_color)  

            
            pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()

Here is my settings module:
class Settings:

    def __init__(self):
        
        self.screen_width = 1080
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.bg_color = (100, 10, 200)

I have made sure the files are names correctly, made sure I imported it correctly and that they are in the same file. This is from Python Crash course by Eric Mathes

do you mean that they are in the same folder not file ?

so you should have a file in the same folder and the main module "main.py" called "settings.py"...  Can you confirm this ?

please provide full error trace and project structure

Make sure your directory looks like this:
/your_project_directory/
│
├── main.py          # Your main module with the AlienInvasion class
└── settings.py      # Your settings module


also, when I run it on command promt I do /python main.py correct?

yes should look like this: python main.py

wtvr it didn't work :/

can you please go into terminal where your directory with this project files is and type tree then send that to me
